# What's an easy to use Photo Effects Software on Mac

Tags: mac, photos

I'm looking for a photo effects software that runs on a mac to do photo effects, such as inversion of colors, pop art, etc.  It should be easy to use.  Kind of like how iPhoto has certain effects, but that's very limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite expensive but still the best one for me: [Adobe Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/photoshop/)

If your searching for a cheaper on (with some basic photo effects in it): [Acorn](http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/)

Please also take a look at previous questions asked here (collection of cheap programs):
[best-cheap-or-free-image-editing-application-for-mac](http://best-cheap-or-free-image-editing-application-for-mac)

Answer (score 1):

The **[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/macintosh/)** (GNU Image Manipulation Program) is one of the best image processing programs available.

its free and open source.

Comment: and has very little to do with "photo effects software".
He's asking for a hammer, not a toolbox.